# GCC: Break compilation on "control reaches end of non-void function"

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

When I add

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wreturn-type"
```

the compiler produces warnings, not errors for each missing `return`. How can I make it turn this particular warning into an error?

Test code:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wreturn-type"

int foo(int x)
{
    if (x) return 8;
}

int main(int narg, char* arg[])
{
    foo(narg);
}
```

I have tried with

> i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
>
> i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.6)

UPDATE: I have tried `-Werror=return-type` as suggested by @sastraxi, but it has the same effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try passing `-Werror=return-type` to gcc!

Comment: That is correct. But make it look like an answer, rather than a question.

Comment: I get an error even without adding it, when running with g++ or gcc 4.5.2-8ubuntu4.

Comment: Apple's gccs are different and old, I guess you just can't.  The `-Werror=<arg>` is a new feature (added in 4.4 methinks)

Comment: It was my fault, I didn't read the question closely enough to see it was pre-4.4. If you want, you can use `-Werror` outright to turn all warnings into errors.